# Forge Viewer - BimWalk Teleportation where i can find the code

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I am trying to implement a feature of teleportation from one place to another

just like when we double click on an object in first person view and it take u directly to that object

I have tried from below link for teleportation
[Forge Viewer - BimWalk Teleportation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634660/forge-viewer-bimwalk-teleportation/65120661#65120661)
but I didn't find any code related to the below code

can any one help me how can I do this required

Answer (score 0):

The code of Forge Viewer and its extensions is not available unfortunately. You *can* however see (and even step through) the code using the browser dev tools. For example, in the Network tab you can see the viewer requesting this JavaScript file:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/BimWalk/BimWalk.js

That's the viewer extension implementing the BimWalk tool, and you're free to explore the implementation there.